# Cannot scrape glassdoor rating's stars

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to figure out a way to get these stars, but the stars are the same in all attributes, both the green ones and the grey ones. These are reviews by the users not the overall company review. How can I get the number of rated stars?(star ratings) If it all.

[image]

Comment: The color of the stars is determined by the CSS class for the parent `div`. If you inspect the element you'll see the `background` property has a `linear-gradient` containing a green fill percentage. 80% -> 4/5 stars are green etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Dan explained in the comments, you can find the css (`.css-1ihykkv`) applied in the class. Within this css, you'll get the `linear-gradient` in `background` attribute. Also you can find the percentage of green and grey color used for rating.
Check screen shot here:[image]

Once you find this css and its attribute you can extract the percentage data. Sharing an example below on how to extract `.css` data:

```
bgColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]")).getCssValue("background-color")
print bgColor
```

The output should be like this:

```
rgba(0, 123, 255, 1)
```

Try extracting the data from the `background` attribute and you can use the percentage data for different ratings like Culture & Values etc.

Comment: @Abhishek Rai, let me know if my suggestion helped you out in any way. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that always the same css class is used for the same number of stars. For example the the css class for four stars is "css-94nhxw" and for one star is "css-1mfncox". I used this in my code to find out which of the classes is used for which rating.
For example my code for the subrating worklife balance looks like this:

```
def scrape_work_life_balance(gdReview):
        try:
            gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span [not@class ="SVGInline d-flex css-hcqxoa"]').text
            return "Null"                                           
        except:
            try:
                gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div [@class="tooltipContainer"]/div [@class="content"]/ul[@class="pl-0"]/li/div[text()="Work/Life Balance"]/following-sibling::div[@class="css-11w4osi e1hd5jg10"]').text
                return "5"
            except:
                try:
                    gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div [@class="tooltipContainer"]/div [@class="content"]/ul[@class="pl-0"]/li/div[text()="Work/Life Balance"]/following-sibling::div[@class="css-94nhxw e1hd5jg10"]').text
                    return "4"
                except:
                    try:
                        gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div [@class="tooltipContainer"]/div [@class="content"]/ul[@class="pl-0"]/li/div[text()="Work/Life Balance"]/following-sibling::div[@class="css-k58126 e1hd5jg10"]').text
                        return "3"
                    except:
                        try:
                            gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div [@class="tooltipContainer"]/div [@class="content"]/ul[@class="pl-0"]/li/div[text()="Work/Life Balance"]/following-sibling::div[@class="css-1lp3h8x  e1hd5jg10"]').text
                            return "2"
                        except:
                            try:
                                gdReview.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div [@class="tooltipContainer"]/div [@class="content"]/ul[@class="pl-0"]/li/div[text()="Work/Life Balance"]/following-sibling::div[@class="css-1mfncox e1hd5jg10"]').text
                                return "1"
                            except:
                                return "Zero"
```

Just keep in mind that css classes can change. Glasdoor just changed them in the last months and I updated them today.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to get them is to access the company profile and get the star rating right from that profile. It must be visible right after the stars. Something like this [image]

Comment: These are reviews by individuals. All are different. It isn't the overall company score.

Comment: You could have mentioned it.

Comment: Yep, wasn't that the rule over here?

Comment: I am not complaining. Just responding.